# Json String created in Wrong Format

Tags: android, json, http, android-networking

I have to send request body in Http request in below format:

```
 {
  "flag":false, 
  "Ids":["xyz","abc"]
}
```

I was trying like:

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> requestParamsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    requestParamsMap.put("flag",false);

    ArrayList<String> IdList = new ArrayList<>();
    IdList.add("xyz");
    IdList.add("abc");
    requestParamsMap.put("Ids", IdList.toString());
```

And then I was converting requestParamsMap to json string. But I am not getting request body in desired format.

I want to create a generalized method which can return me data in this type of format, so that I can use it throughout application.

Any help would be appreciated.. !!!

Comment: obviously you need to use some json serializer ... LinkedHashMap.toString() will not return json automagically (neither ArrayList.toString() will return json array)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
 JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("flag","xyz");
        JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
        array.put("xyz");
        array.put("abc");

        object.put("Ids",array);

        //added a log to see the output
        Log.e("output",object.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`object.toString()` should contain exactly the json you want in string format. You can use a loop to populate the contents of the jsonArray or JSONObject depending on the number of items you have

Answer (score 0):

Its not that though at all, output you want is JSONArray inside JSONObject and JSONObject inside another JSONObject. So, you can create them seperately and then can put in together. as below.

**CODE**

```
try {
        JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put("lv1");
        jsonArray.put("lv2");

        jsonObject.put("mk1", "mv1");
        jsonObject.put("mk2", jsonArray);
        parent.put("root", jsonObject);
        Log.d("output", parent.toString(2));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 {
       "root": {
         "mk1": "mv1",
         "mk2": [
           "lv1",
           "lv2"
         ]
       }
     }
```